# ASCX.cs code behind page not pulling value from the ascx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ascx

I have a checkbox that resets itself on postback to the code behind page, I'm now trying to set the value of the checkbox in the code behind page. But I am unable to do so below is my code the hidden field doesn't get set, any help would be appreciated:

ASPX

```
    <asp:Checkbox id="HiddenDossetCheckValue" value="" runat="server" type="hidden"/>

function DossettesSet()
    {
    var zCheckBox = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenDossetCheckValue.ClientID%>');


    var checkBoxBool = zCheckBox.checked;


        if(zCheckBox.checked === true)
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=HiddenDossetCheckValue.ClientID%>').value = "1";
            console.log(document.getElementById(HiddenDossetCheckValue).value);
        }

        if (zCheckBox.checked === false) {

            document.getElementById('<%=HiddenDossetCheckValue.ClientID%>').value = "0";
            //console.log(document.getElementById(HiddenDossetCheckValue).value);
        }

    }
```

ASCX.CS

```
 public string CheckBoxValue
    {
        get
        {
            bool hiddenField;
            hiddenField = HiddenDossetCheckValue.Checked;
            if (ViewState["HiddenDossetCheckValue"] != null)
                return (string)ViewState["HiddenDossetCheckValue"];
            else
                return null;               
        }
        set
        {
            bool hiddenField = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is this `<asp:Checkbox id="HiddenDossetCheckValue" value="" runat="server" type="hidden"/>` control? A hidden or a checkbox field? It really does not make much sense. If you want to hide a checkbox you should do it from the css or js adding 'display:none' to it ...

Comment: You are trying to add a value to a checkbox asp control, and this is not available. A checkbox is checked or not, it does not have a value.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the checkbox field to a variable and not using it?

Why not just:

```
zCheckBox.value = '1';
console.log(zCheckBox.value);
```